# How does the INT datatype work in PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I observed a strange thing in INT for MySQL. I declared the length of int as `1`, and to my surprise, the table accepts a value of `1234565675`.

Screen shot for the same:

[image]

Can someone let me know what is exactly happening?

Comment: You don't declare actual lengths of int data types in MySQL; that numeric specifier is/can be used as a hint for display purposes; but every `int` field holds a 32-bit integer value.

Comment: AFAIK without `ZEROFILL` the "length" of INT has no meaning.